# Enable S2S Streaming on OpenFire AWS EC2

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to enable XMPP federation on my OpenFire server. I've created the DNS SRV Records and they are listing correctly. But still I am not able to connect to the server from any other providers like jabber.org & google talk. I've checked my settings at http://www.imtrends.com/ and it is showing that "Server-To-Server Stream", "Personal Eventing via PubSub" and  "Client-To-Server SSL Stream" are not available.

[image: Screenshot]

What is Server-To-Server Stream and how to enable this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have must verifique to firewall not reject the connections and the S2S it is enable in the server configuration.

The port used by s2s is 5269 by default.